# Installing modules in Python without command line

Tags: python, pygame, pip

Hi I am going interstate and will only have my laptop with me, I do not have admin rights on it and the use of Cmd is banned. I want to be able to use Pygame on my laptop. How can I install the module without command line?

Comment: In what way is the use of cmd banned (I assume cmd.exe)?  Could you: `os.system('cmd')`?

Comment: Set up a development environment inside a VM using something like Virtualbox?

Comment: There's a Pygame installer on the website. Or use `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a C compiler, you can download the source from http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel comfortable with Linux, you could use a live USB drive to boot into Linux and work there (without installing anything to the actual hard drive), or you could set up a new OS inside of a virtual machine. Good luck.